# Is it possible to write an upright Greek letter in math mode on Stack Exchange?

Tags: mathjax

I'd like to write all mathematical constants (this includes some Greek letters) in upright style – here on Stack Exchange (math mode). Is it possible to write an upright pi, for example?

It bothers me pretty much, since, in any document (also math answers, questions...), either all constants should be upright, or no constants should be upright.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is off-topic in this site. You should as this at https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It says that I cannot ask anything because I do not have enough reputation. Could you please help me with this? Also, when providing a link there, it says the post does not exist or is not linked to the current user.

Comment: Apparently you need 5 reputation to ask on meta. Try again, now you should be able to do it ;)